# olMailItem - 91 object variable or with block variable no set

Tags: variables, object

I am trying to find solution for below error:

"91 - Object variable or With block variable not set"

It is clearly that error occurs on this line:

**Set uMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)**

This is whole sub:

**Private Sub PutInOutlook()**

```
Dim OutApp As Object, Ky
Set OutApp = GetOutlook
Dim uMail As Object, I@

For Each Ky In pDict.Keys
    I = 1 + I
    pStatusBar.UpdateLittleMeter "Saving email " & I & " of " & pDict.Count & " " & Ky, I / pDict.Count

    Set uMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    pDict.Item(Ky).FillMailItemWithData iMailItem:=uMail

    Set uMail = Nothing
Next Ky

Set OutApp = Nothing
```

**End Sub**

**Now, important things:**

- **It is not working since upgrade from WIN XP to WIN 7 week ago.**
- This tool works almost 2 years with no problems.
- There were no changes in the code.
- There is about 40 people using it.
- Problem is only on one PC.
- There are different users with WIN 7 and it works fine.

I checked references and everything looks ok.

I have no idea what is causing this problem, also i didn't found solution for this in internet.

If somebody could give ma hint what is causing this I would be more than very happy :)

P.S. Sorry for my english, it is possible I made some mistakes in text.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely **GetOutlook()** at line `Set OutApp = GetOutlook` is not returning reference to Outlook object so your **OutApp** variable is not initialized.

I have met similar situations in the past. This can be caused by

1. **different Outlook version is installed**: for example all machines use 2007, this uses 2010

   - check inner workings of GetOutlook how Outlook instance is obtained

     - if the Outlook is bound in **References** window, you can swap the reference to currently installed Outlook version and this usually helps. Check menu `Tools` > `References` and compare what you see there to other machines where code runs without problems.
2. **damaged Outlook installation**

   - try running Repair installation procedure, then check again